# How to find the correspond hash algorithm?

Tags: cryptography, hash, file-encryption, md5, hashcat

I'm currently working on a project. but i still facing some issue due to some crypted data. i know the plaintext and got the correspond hash.

```
plaintext: C018AE45B37DAE665486F4151E0C1E6F
Hash: rROkd+H57WFtdkbkOEgTWLG0zqFpo/++2ttu0YPXvqNn2l3FcJZqJg==
```

i have tried to find out with some online analyzer and also with hashcat but didn't get anything.
can you advise me a tool or a process to find out the corresponding hash algorithm used?
thanks in advance .

Comment: Hint:  It looks like the output hash has been base64-encoded.  When tackling these types of problems, it's helpful to start by looking at the number of bytes in the output hash, as this will often shed some light on what type of hash this is.  For this case, you can do `echo -n 'rROkd+H57WFtdkbkOEgTWLG0zqFpo/++2ttu0YPXvqNn2l3FcJZqJg==' | base64 -d | xxd`.  You'll see that this is 40 bytes, or 320 bits.  What hash function produces outputs with 320 bits?

Comment: As someone else said it in comments, it looks like the data have been base64 encoded.
You can see that by examining the characters [(see Base64 characters)](https://base64.guru/learn/base64-characters). Just to be clear, Base64 encoding is **not** a hash function, and the output is not a hash. Also, the data is not encrypted but encoded.

Comment: @FrixosKallenos but it is also hashed ...

Comment: thanks, it seems like its base64 encoded, so by using a reverse tool function i will be able to retrieve data

Comment: by using the Cyberchief tool, i get for this value : ..`¤wáùíamvFä8H.X±´Î¡i£ÿ¾ÚÛnÑ.×¾£gÚ]Åp.j&`

Comment: is there any way to reach the correct data  ?